# Swift - Check that video has been played continuously until the end

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, swift5

I'm using a `AVPlayer` to display a video. 
I wish to make sure that the user has seen the video continuously until the end.

Using

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerVC.player?.currentItem)
```

I'm able to know when the video has finished, but the problem is that the user can drag to the end of the video using the playback controllers.

I thought that `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemTimeJumped` was the solution, but this notification is posted even when the video is played normally. What I mean is that with :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemTimeJumped), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemTimeJumped, object: playerVC.player?.currentItem)
```

and

```
@objc func playerItemTimeJumped(note: NSNotification) {
        hasTimeJumped = true
        print("Time has jumped !")
}
```

"Time has jumped !" is printed even if I watched the video without touching anything. Is that behaviour normal? If yes, how can I check that the user has watched the video continuously until the end? Am I forced to create a timer variable and check if that variable if bigger than the length of the video?

Kind regards

Comment: AVPlayer has delegate methods which you could look at. Have a look at the [AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate?language=objc). Scroll down to **Responding to Navigation Events** section.

Comment: Within your callback, can you inspect note variable? Maybe it has some useful info.

Comment: @chirag90 I looked into it and it seems that it could work. My only problem is that when I inherited from `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` the methods that are in **Responding to Navigation Events** don't appear, while the methods in **Responding to Picture in Picture Playback Events** do. I called
func skipToNextItem(for: AVPlayerViewController) {
        print("skipToNextItem called")
    }
anyways, and didn't forget to `playerVC.delegate = self` but nothing was printed.

Comment: @NicoC sorry my mistake, just read that them delegate methods in `Responding to navigation events` are for tvOS and not for iOS

Comment: @NiravBhatt Unfortunately, the variable note has not useful info (I think). It's the Notification, so I can retrieve its name, as well as the object associated with the notification (in my case : `playerVC.player?.currentItem`)